# Render PDF Streamed from API In HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf

I have an API's response which is contain a PDF Stream like:

`response.data = "%PDF-1.7↵%����↵1 0 obj ↵<<↵/FormType 1..."`

Then I am try to use :

```
<object data={response.data} type="application/pdf" width="800" height="400">
```

for render pdf stream to my browser but it does not work.

**Question:**
How can I render it into my HTML and show it to my browser?

Comment: remove curly braces from data source. it should be `data=response.data`

Comment: I use React for my client, so that need to be have curly braces